# If purchase is successful enable gallery in context menu

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase

When purchase from the user is successful, I want to enable the "user gallery" item in the context menu. However, my code does nothing and I would be grateful for some help.Thanks!

This is my onCreateOptionsMenu method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    if (purchaseSuccessful = false) {
        menu.findItem(R.id.userGallery).setEnabled(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.purchase).setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        menu.findItem(R.id.userGallery).setEnabled(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.purchase).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

and this is where I set up my "purchaseSuccessful" Boolean:

```
IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener mPurchaseFinishedListener = 
      new IabHelper.OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabPurchaseFinished(IabResult result, Purchase purchase) {
                  if (result.isFailure()) {
                       purchaseSuccessful = false;
                       return;
                  } else if (purchase.getSku().equals(ITEM_SKU)) {
                       consumeItem();
                       purchaseSuccessful = true;
                       invalidateOptionsMenu();
                  }
            }
};
```

Comment: `if(purchaseSuccessful = false)` will set `purchaseSuccessful` to `false`, then check thr value of `purchaseSuccessful` (which will always be `false`). You should be using `==`, or even `if(!purchaseSuccessful)`

Comment: Thank you so much!